# interact between google map API and fusion table in order to get data

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have a fusion table of polygons that can show on my google map javascript API.

The link is right here: https://fusiontables.google.com/data?docid=1O-VUAKZnf0ey4-BttV7xsjXh9pIf6qK60G7-30eB

In my fusion table, there is some districts of the map which has been divided by polygons.

I wish that when I add a marker on my google map javascript API, I can identify which district(polygon) is the marker at.

Is there a way that the google map Javascript API can retrieve data from the fusion table?

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you are after Fusion Tables Layer.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer

You basically can create fusion tables layer and add to your map. Hope it points you to the right direction.